# What does this Wireshark capture filter do

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis, capture

I was reading through a guide where I saw the following **Wireshark capture filter** used.

```
(tcp[2:2] > 1500 and tcp[2:2] < 1550)
```

I had a brief look over Wireshark's website which listed their documentation for the various commands, but I could not make any sense of it. Any tutorials I found covered other helpful, but not relevant, ways to capture filter, for example `host www.example.com and not (port 80 or port 25)` which at least made sense.

Could someone please explain what each part of this capture filter is doing?

Answer (score 3):

The capture filter isn't really Wireshark syntax but that of the underlying capture library. Depending on that library, syntax may differ somewhat.

`tcp[2:2]` means *from the TCP header, at two bytes offset, take two bytes/octets* which is the destination port number.

Accordingly, `(tcp[2:2] > 1500 and tcp[2:2] < 1550)` means "capture TCP-carrying packets with destination ports from 1501 to 1549".

With newer capture libraries, `tcp dst portrange 1501-1549` is the equivalent (and easier to memorize).